# Ошибка при работе "хуков"

Tags: winapi

Здравствуйте!

Написал небольшую прогу по работе с хуками, записывает в файл нажатия клавиш, но вот недавно начали выскакивать ошибки при запуске.... Перестал работать блокнот, проводник иногда виснет.... хотя пару дней назад никаких проблем не было.... Стоит антивирус Аваст. Может он блокировать dll? или еще что могло случиться?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понял что отключить?

Comment: Может блокировать, пробуйте это поделие отключить.

Comment: Аваст отключить. А вообще по хорошему надо бы код выложить